# Una buena implementación del enumerado?

Tags: java, enum

Tengo el siguiente enumerado:

```
package ventas;

public enum Producto {


    DVD_A6H225(new Categoria("AV015","Audio/Video"),new Fabricante("SAMSUNG",new Ubicacion("ITALIA",1075,"CABA")),50,8600.00,"DVDSAMSUNG-A6H225"),
    HOME_Z1000(new Categoria("AA012","Audio/Video"),new Fabricante("PHILIPS",new Ubicacion("MAIPU",876,"CABA")),60,12250.00,"HOMETHEATERPHILIPS-Z1000"),
    SMARTPHONE_J7(new Categoria("J9yH22F","Celulares"),new Fabricante("SAMSUNG",new Ubicacion("GENERAL BELGRANO",1268,"CORDOBACAPITAL")),85,14000.00,"SMARTPHONE_J7"),
    SMARTPHONE_V10(new Categoria("J9Y46F","Celulares"),new Fabricante("MOTOROLA",new Ubicacion("GENERAL SAN MARTIN",2754,"ROSARIO")),80,15600.00,"SMARTPHONEMOTO_V10"),
    LAVARROPAS_S72H(new Categoria("E7H52A","Electrodomesticos"),new Fabricante("WIHRPOOL",new Ubicacion("GUEMES",3532,"CABA")),50,13000.50,"LAVARROPASWHIR_S72H"),
    SMARTTV_HK117(new Categoria("AV019","Audio/Video"),new Fabricante("NOBLEX",new Ubicacion("VUELTADEOBRIGADO",3542,"RIO GALLEGOS")),100,25600.00,"SMARTNOBLEXHK117");

    private Categoria categoria;
    private Fabricante fabricante;
    private Integer stock;
    private Double precio;
    private String identificador;


    private Producto(Categoria categoria, Fabricante fabricante, Integer stock, Double precio, String identificador) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.fabricante = fabricante;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.identificador = identificador;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.getIdentificador() + " = Stock: " + this.getStock() + " , Precio unitario: $" + this.getPrecio();
    }


    public void descontarStock(Integer monto) {
        this.setStock(getStock()-monto);
    }

    public void devolverStock(Integer monto) {
        this.setStock(getStock()+monto);
    }

    public Categoria getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(Categoria categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public Fabricante getFabricante() {
        return fabricante;
    }

    public void setFabricante(Fabricante fabricante) {
        this.fabricante = fabricante;
    }

    public Integer getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Integer stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public Double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(Double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getIdentificador() {
        return identificador;
    }

    public void setIdentificador(String identificador) {
        this.identificador = identificador;
    }
}
```

Estos productos son de una empresa vendedora de electrodomésticos, las personas que realizan compras pueden comprar y devolver productos, la cantidad adquirida se descontara del stock del articulo correspondiente. Solo puede comprar o devolver si es mayor de edad.

```
package ventas;
import java.io.*;

public class Empresa {

    private BufferedWriter compras_out;
    private BufferedWriter devoluciones_out;

    Empresa(){
        try {
            compras_out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("compras.out.txt"));
            devoluciones_out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("devoluciones.out.txt"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("(!) Error al inicializar los archivos");
        }
    }

    public Boolean vender(Persona persona, Producto producto, Integer cantidad) {
        if(persona.esMayor()) {
            if(producto.getStock()>=cantidad) {
                try {
                    compras_out.write("" + persona.getDni() + " " + producto.getIdentificador() + " " + cantidad + " $" + (cantidad*producto.getPrecio()));
                    compras_out.newLine();
                    producto.descontarStock(cantidad);
                    System.out.println("Compra realizada, Cliente: " + persona.getNombre() + " , Dni: " + persona.getDni());
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("(!) Error de escritura");
                }
            } else  System.out.println("(!) No hay stock suficiente");
        } else System.out.println("(!) El cliente debe ser mayor de edad");
        return false;
    }

    public Boolean devolucion(Persona persona, Producto producto, Integer cantidad) {
        if(persona.esMayor()) {
            try {
                devoluciones_out.write("" + persona.getDni() + " " + producto.getIdentificador() + " " + cantidad + " $" + (cantidad*producto.getPrecio()));
                devoluciones_out.newLine();
                producto.devolverStock(cantidad);
                System.out.println("Devolucion realizada, Cliente: " + persona.getNombre() + " , Dni: " + persona.getDni());
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("(!) Error de escritura");
            }
            return true;
        } else System.out.println("(!) El cliente debe ser mayor de edad");
        return false;
    }

    public void cerrarArchivos() {
        try {
            compras_out.close();
            devoluciones_out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("(!) Problema al cerrar los archivos");
        }
    }


    public BufferedWriter getCompras_out() {
        return compras_out;
    }

    public void setCompras_out(BufferedWriter compras_out) {
        this.compras_out = compras_out;
    }

    public BufferedWriter getDevoluciones_out() {
        return devoluciones_out;
    }

    public void setDevoluciones_out(BufferedWriter devoluciones_out) {
        this.devoluciones_out = devoluciones_out;
    }
}
```

Este es un pequeño test de los métodos de la clase Empresa:

```
package ventas;

public abstract class Test {

    /** @author Balsamo jorge */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Empresa garbarino = new Empresa();

        Persona matias = new Persona(1245678,18,"Matias");
        Persona jorge = new Persona(45869202,24,"Jorge");
        Persona brian = new Persona(38541203,26,"Brian");
        Persona kevin = new Persona(39451206,25,"Kevin");
        Persona leonardo = new Persona(47512322,17,"Leonardo");
        Persona rodrigo = new Persona(45127481,32,"Rodrigo");

        System.out.println();

        garbarino.vender(matias, Producto.SMARTPHONE_V10, 2);
        garbarino.vender(jorge, Producto.HOME_Z1000, 3);
        garbarino.vender(brian, Producto.LAVARROPAS_S72H, 1);
        garbarino.vender(kevin, Producto.DVD_A6H225, 4);
        garbarino.vender(rodrigo, Producto.SMARTTV_HK117, 5);

        System.out.println();

        garbarino.vender(leonardo, Producto.HOME_Z1000, 7);

        System.out.println();

        garbarino.devolucion(matias, Producto.SMARTPHONE_V10, 1);
        garbarino.devolucion(jorge, Producto.HOME_Z1000, 2);
        garbarino.devolucion(brian, Producto.LAVARROPAS_S72H, 1);
        garbarino.devolucion(matias, Producto.SMARTPHONE_V10, 3);
        garbarino.devolucion(rodrigo, Producto.SMARTTV_HK117, 2);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println(Producto.DVD_A6H225.toString());
        System.out.println(Producto.HOME_Z1000.toString());
        System.out.println(Producto.LAVARROPAS_S72H.toString());
        System.out.println(Producto.SMARTPHONE_J7.toString());
        System.out.println(Producto.SMARTPHONE_V10.toString());
        System.out.println(Producto.SMARTTV_HK117.toString());

        garbarino.cerrarArchivos();

    }

}
```

El codigo funciona, mi pregunta concreta es si esta es una buena implementacion del enumerado, porque puedo acceder a el enum desde cualquier clase y eso no se si es correcto, quizas deberia crear una Clase Productos normal, esta seria atributo privado de la clase Empresa, en un vector o una coleccion tipo ArrayList, y de esa manera estaria encapsulada para las demas clases. Espero haber explicado bien mi duda.

Comment: Si creas una clase Producto que oculte tu *enum* ¿cómo vas a vender o devolver? Tal como tienes montada la clase empresa necesitas acceso a tu *enum* para hacer las operaciones. Si la nueva clase Producto tiene métodos para exponer el *enum* privado vas a estar en la misma. Así como lo tienes no está mal, yo me quedaba así a a no ser que inventes algo mucho más elaborado que te va a complicar la vida ;-)

Comment: Usar un enum obliga a generar una nueva versión de la aplicación cada vez que cambies la lista de productos. Un Enum debe usarse para cosas que no cambian nunca, los productos deberían estar en una base de datos